# Cloud Functions - CORS - Cannot read property 'origin' of undefined

Tags: firebase, cors, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to set up cors into my project but after installing the package I am getting error after I try to deploy to Firebase.

Error

```
Error: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers.
TypeError: Cannot read property 'origin' of undefined
```

My Code - index.js

```
const cors = require('cors')({
  origin: true
});
```

Packages

```
"dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "~7.0.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^2.2.0",
    "express": "*",
    "cors": "*"
  },
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to use the cors with express. And i am not sure if you could set properties on a module import.

Here i have an example how i add cors to my express app.

```
const cors = require("cors");

const app = express();
app.use(cors({ origin: true }));
```

With Typescript it looks like this.

```
import * as cors from 'cors';

const app = express();
app.use(cors({ origin: true }));
```

Comment: You do not have to use cors with express.